# CLEditor dynamic adding text

Tags: jquery

I'm using [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/docs/GettingStarted.html#optionalParameters) for a website I'm working on. I'm trying to add dynamic text to the textarea with jQuery. Usually I'll be using something like:

```
$('#myText').val('Here some dynamic text');
```

But this just doesn't work with CLEditor. When disabling CLEditor it works fine however, enabling it again the text just disappears. I tried looking on the website for a solution, but I can't find any. Anyone had the same problem lately?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `updateTextArea` under options looks like its the callback u need :)

Comment: @Val I think I'm doing something wrong. I just tried this:
$("#myText").cleditor()[0].updateTextArea('Testing');

Still nothing happens yet.

Comment: `$("#input").cleditor({width:500, height:250,updateTextArea:function (){....}})`

Comment: Ok...Now I understand what I did wrong. Thanks a million. I can't choose your comment as the answer. Care to post it as an answer so I can give you some points? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#input").cleditor({width:500, height:250,updateTextArea:function (){....}})
```

Comment: In order to get this to work I had to do $("#input).val("testing"); $("#input").cleditor()[0].updateFrame(); before the text would appear

Comment: A bit more of an example would be helpful.... is the function returning a string to update the text area with?  Should the function handle the updating?

Comment: @webnet what do you mean? is it returning a string? you are assigning a function to the updateTextArea, and you can use return this, to remain chainability.

Answer (score 24):

CLEditor update iFrame content when blur method of textarea is called:

```
//make CLEditor
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text').cleditor();
});

//set value
$('#text').val('new text data').blur();
```

Comment: +1 I have been looking for this for quite a long time. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue and finally found something in the comments that was helpful, so here is what I have; hopefully this will come in handy to someone down the road.

```
// initializing the cleditor on document ready
var $editor = $('#description').cleditor()
```

Then when I get some html and need to dynamically insert it into the cleditor, here is what I use:

```
// update the text of the textarea
// just some simple html is used for testing purposes so you can see this working
$('#description').val('<strong>testing</strong>');

// update cleditor with the latest html contents
$editor.updateFrame();
```

Comment: Excellent, worked prefectly, so simple compared to some of the other answers. People should vote this answer up!

Answer (score 2):

For example if for someone it will be helpful, you can use it.

Situation, i need on change dropdown field value,  to change the content of cleditor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Define and load CLEditor
    $("#input").cleditor({
        width: 800,
        height: 300,
        controls: "bold italic underline subscript superscript | color highlight removeformat | alignleft center alignright justify | table | undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | print source ",
            useCSS: false
    });


// on change dropdown value
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
// doing AJAX request by GET
        $.get(
// pushing AJAX request to this file
                'ajax/change_dimmensions_table.php',
// pushing some data, from which to determine, what content I need to get back
                    {'dropdown_value':$('#dropdown').val()},
                function(data, textStatus) {
// Clearing the content of CLEditor, adding new content to CLEditor
                        $("#input").cleditor({width:800, height:300, updateTextArea:function (){}})[0].clear().execCommand("inserthtml", data, null, null);
            },
                    'html'
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

change_dimmensions_table.php:

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

if ( ! empty( $_GET['dropdown_value']))
{
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('database');
    mysql_query("SET names utf8");

    $sql = "
SELECT
    `html_content`
FROM
    `templates`
WHERE
    `dropdown` = '{$_GET['dropdown_value']}'
LIMIT 1
    ";

    $result = mysql_query( $sql) or die( mysql_error() . " SQL: {$sql}");

    if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result))
        {
            $html = $row->html_content;
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $html))
    {
        echo $html;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kind of a late answer, but:

```
$('#myText').cleditor()[0].execCommand('inserthtml','Here some dynamic text');
```

is really the simplest answer, if you're asking me. The other simple answer was given by Francis Lewis above.

Answer (score 0):

execCommand is charm, but it does not work in IE, val().blur() is reliable